# Ruby spaceship (gem), revoke method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to revoke certificate from apple development portal using https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship

Most of the methods are working fine expect the revoke method:

Example :

```
[52] pry(main)> Spaceship::Portal::Certificate::DevelopmentPush.all
```

will list to me all developmentpush certficate ,

There is revoke method but I couldn't figure out the right syntax for it

tested couple of syntax such :

```
[52] pry(main)> Spaceship::Portal::Certificate::revoke_certificate!('id', 'type')

NameError: wrong constant name RevokeCertificate!
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spaceship-0.22.0/lib/spaceship/base.rb:153:in `const_defined?'
```

anyone knows the right syntax as this spaceship has no good docs or reference at all ,

thanks in advance

Comment: yes my bad , i was talking about spaceship library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Spaceship::Portal::Certificate::revoke_certificate!
```

This looks like you're attempting a method call. Try:

```
Spaceship::Portal::Certificate.revoke!
```

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/certificate.rb#L317

Note that it says:

```
# Revoke the certificate. You shouldn't use this method probably.
```